# how do I control the order of child controls when adding to my parent control?

Tags: vb.net, panel

I have a panel (call it main_box) and I add about 20 more panels inside of it. Each of the child panels is placed right under the one above it. When I resize the form, the child panels change size (like I want them to), but they don't reposition themselves inside the parent box, so I need to do that manually.

I am trying:

```
Dim vert_pos as integer = 0
For Each o As Object In main_box.Controls
    o.location = New Point(0, vert_pos)
    vert_pos += o.height
Next
```

but the child boxes get positioned out of order. They do not appear in the same order that I added them to the parent box.

How can I ensure that they are repositioned in order?

Comment: Are we to assume "main_box" is an autoscroll panel?

Comment: How about a `FlowLayoutPanel`?

Comment: yes, it is an autoscroll panel

Comment: what advantage would a flowlayout panel give me?

Comment: The FlowLayoutPanel would automatically rearrange the controls for you...

Comment: Start by turning on `Option Strict` the controls collection contains controls not objects and "Location" is not a property of Object.  To manually reposition, you should use `AutoScrollPosition` X or Y depending on whether they scroll vertically or horizontally

Comment: I tried the flowlayoutpanel and it does not work like I need it to.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was creating an array; and each time I added a child panel to the main_box, I also added it to the array. Then I just iterate through the array instead of the main_box.controls and the order stays correct.

Comment: Why the hit and run down vote? What's wrong with this solution? It works perfectly. You don't like me finding the answer on my own?